# First thing, there is always an exception - what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I cast a shadow as dark as I
>
> I have been found in a pie
>
> Insects sing, in the dead of night
>
> Many together is quite the sight

What am I? And what does each section of the riddle mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> Blackbird

Reasoning:
I cast a shadow as dark as I

> Blackbirds do cast a shadow and the dark as I refers to the color of the bird (Black)

I have been found in a pie

> refers to the nursery rhyme "4 and 20 blackbirds baked in a pie"

Insects sing, in the dead of night

> The Beatles (insects) sing "Blackbird" which has the lyric "Blackbirds singing in the dead of night"

Many together is quite the sight

> Blackbirds generally nest separately but they do form "super flocks" when migrating.

The title refers to

> a black swan which is a black bird and a rare (or exceptional) occurrence.

Comment: Well done, the final answer is correct but you haven't managed to get the insects line or the title. Hope you don't mind but I'll leave open for now and hopefully you can get the final sections.

Comment: Gotcha, I've updated my answer and added a reasoning for the title.

Comment: Damn. I figured this was the answer but could only make it fit the first two lines. I should've had your confidence to post it :-P (+1)

Comment: For the last line, maybe a collective noun? (I couldn't find an apt one, but) otherwise the line seems a bit empty - same thing could describe lots of different creatures, and these particular ones aren't gregarious anyway.

Comment: @MobileGlick Nice updates

Comment: @Ran'Thor I added the last line mainly for rhyming sakes, in hindsight I should have worked in this line a bit longer